# Spring MVC - getting model data after a redirect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I want to pass data to a view after a redirect. for example, I press a button and it redirects me to a page with data from the controller. I am trying to use RedirectAttribute which everyone is suggesting but I can not get it working. Any help is appreciated.

index.jsp:

```
<a href="user.htm">Display All Users</a>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user.htm")
public ModelAndView addUser(RedirectAttributes redirAtt) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:user");
    String out = "All User Details: ";
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from Users").list();
        mv.addObject("users", result);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    redirAtt.addFlashAttribute("message", out);
    return mv;
}
```

jsp that I want data displayed on: user.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>${message}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${message}</h1><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Nickname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${users}"  var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.nickname}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

No data is displayed when the page is redirected.

I also did my controller this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm")
public String addUser(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    String out = "All User Details: ";
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from Users").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "testing testing tesing");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/user.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user.jsp")
public ModelAndView test(@ModelAttribute("message") String myMessage) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
    mv.addObject("message", myMessage);
    return mv;

}
```

When i tried this, the redirected url is :

```
http://localhost:8080/projname/user.jsp?message=testing+testing+tesing
```

so I think the attributes are being passed over but maybe I am outputting wrong?

Comment: if you use redirect,you just can passing parameters via URL,which means that the values come from the url you see in the browser,you can use it put a single object,but if passing multiple objects,the url size may reach the limit of GET method,so I suggest you change another method:query the object after redirect

Comment: I just want to get the one message value right now. how would I do that?

Comment: you can use *RedirectAttrbutes addAttribute* method to do it ,see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addAttribute-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 5):

there are three possibilities to handle redirect-attributes

1. adding flash/model-attributes to RedirectAttributes
2. adding request-parameter ('dynamic' attributes) to RedirectAttributes
3. adding request-parameter ('dynamic' attributes) to RedirectView

i combined the three possibilities in the following get-methods.

```
@GetMapping("/redirectme")
public RedirectView redirectme(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    // the following attribute is a ModelAttribute
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageA", "A");
    final RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/redirectedpage", true);
    // the following attributes are request-parameter (dynamic Attributes)
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("messageB", "B");
    redirectView.getAttributesMap().put("messageC", "C");
    return redirectView;
}

@GetMapping("/redirectedpage")
public ModelAndView redirectedPage(
        // access FlashAttributes
        final Model model, @ModelAttribute("messageA") final String messageA,
        // access 'dynamic' Attributes
        @RequestParam("messageB") final String messageB, @RequestParam("messageC") final String messageC) {
    final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("red");
    modelAndView.addObject("caption", "App");
    // access FlashAttributes
    modelAndView.addObject("messageA_1", model.asMap().get("messageA"));
    modelAndView.addObject("messageA_2", messageA);
    // access 'dynamic' Attributes
    modelAndView.addObject("messageB", messageB);
    modelAndView.addObject("messageC", messageC);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put  @Controller in top of your controller class.

redirect:/user.jsp -> this should be the relative path to jsp file.

Comment: yes, the controller is working fine, i do not know why the values wont show

Comment: Try this:  Inside @RequestMapping(value = "/user.jsp") ,after creating mv object.  mv.setViewName("user");

Answer (score 0):

If You want to redirect to the direct jsp then use model attribute to bind "message" parameter.

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
mv.addObject("message", out);
```

or if you want to redirect on another controller 
then use RedirectAttributes to bind the "message" parameter like:

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/user.abc");
redirAtt.addFlashAttribute("message", out);
```